# Shortcut key to run (build) code up to the current line in SublimeText3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I use SublimeText3 on macOS for writing my code. I would like to run/build a code up to the current line where cursor is situated.
Is there a shortcut key to do that?

A shortcut key to select all lines from the beginning to the current line will also help. I can use that followed by key binding for build.

Although the example given below is short, I intend to use it in a script containing many lines of code.

Example .py script:

```
 print("a")
 print("b") #keep cursor here and use key board shortcut to run all lines of code up to this line.
 print("c")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text has no built in debugger so there is no run-to-cursor feature.

There are various debugging plugins that can be installed using [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation). Among these there are [Python Debugger](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Debugger) which may be of use to you since you refer to Python in your post and [Sublime Debugger](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Debugger) which *attempts to match Visual Studio Code's Debugger fairly closely*.